How can I dynamically handle TinyMCE fields in Angular when adding or removing fields?
  addMenuItems() {
    this.Form.valueChanges.subscribe((formValues) => {
      this.tinymceElements = '';
      for (let key in formValues) {
        if (formValues.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          const value = formValues[key];
          console.log(`Key: ${key}, Value: ${value}`);
          const menuName = key.replace(/ /g, '');
          this.tinymceElements += `${menuName} `;
          this.editor?.editor.ui.registry.addMenuItem(menuName, {
            text: key,
            icon: 'browse',
            onAction: () => this.editor.editor.insertContent(value),
          });
        }
      }

      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    });
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.editor && this.editor.editor) {
      this.addMenuItems();
    }
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.editor.editor.remove();
  }

I’m using TinyMCE with a custom menu called "Field Values" that contains the latest form values. However, I can only get it to work if I hide the TinyMCE component initially or use mocked data, which prevents the custom menu from initializing properly. How can I fix this to ensure it pulls in the latest form values?

please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue happening, and explanation on what needs to be fixed on the stackblitz

link Here is the link where I intend to place the form values within a menu

link

@NarenMurali you can find the link

will check and let you know when I can, thank you!
